# Custom nav walker: How to acces the $args parameter?

Tags: filters, walker, wp-parse-args

I am creating a custom nav walker. I noticed that the nav walker class from the WordPress core is written rather rough – much of the stuff going on could be spread out through various methods, so I wanted to give that a try.

Currently I am wondering how I can get the `$args` (containing arguments passed to different methods) parameter in my constructor?

Giving it a close look, there is the filter `wp_nav_menu_args` ([source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L241)) that could be used for it like in the following example snippet, but I am wondering if there might be another way to get it:

```
 class My_Custom_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    public function __construct() {
        $args = add_action('wp_nav_menu_args', array($this, 'get_the_args'));
    }

    public function get_the_args($args) {
        return $args;
    }

    […]
```

[A few lines above the filter](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L231), there is probably the first occurrence of `$args`, but is it really written in a way that I can only access it using the filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress Walkers aren't using constructors. They are started up with `walk()` method which is passed arguments as third argument (confusingly not reflected in method signature).

You can capture it into your object's property with something like this:

```
class Args_Walker extends Walker {

    public function walk( $elements, $max_depth ) {

        // we could declare above, but would get incompatible signature
        $args = func_get_arg(2);

        $this->args = $args;

        return parent::walk( $elements, $max_depth, $args );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am not sure if I understand correctly – are you saying that `$args` is available inside the function, although it doesn't get passed to it? Also, what does `func_get_args(2)` do? In the PHP manual it's not mentioned that it's possible to pass a parameter.

Comment: It _does_ get passed to the function, implementation is just a mess. You can pass more to function than arguments it declares and that's what WP is doing in this case. Typo on a function, meant `func_get_arg()` (singular).

Comment: Ah thanks man, now it starts to make a bit more sense! And shivers go down my spine – WordPress is really hard to understand most of the time because it's so convoluted.